# How should we know that which logged in user is using the form in java?

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, hibernate, authentication

Hai all I am creating an application in java in which each user have to log into my application and to use the same swing form. But for each user some items in the form will be different according to their job title. So how could I know that which user is using the form. I had search in Google about this but found no solution. I will be thankful if someone help me out in this issue.

I am using java swing to create the form, MS SQL Server as the server and hibernate framework.

Comment: you need to have user table in your database and with access level like admin , normal user , when you are making login check you can save the username display that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely your own context, that is, the solution will depend on how you've implemented the solution so far.

For example, once the user has logged in, you could get some kind of token from the server (or whoever is validating the user credentials), which could then be used to determine what privileges that the user has.

Regardless of what type of token you get or how you determine the privileges of the user, you will need to pass this information to the UI so that it can use it.

This essentially the same idea as a session concept in web development.

What I've done in the past is had the user details passed to some kind of manager, that validates the credentials and generates a token and returns that token back to the caller.  This token is then required (and is validated by the server) each time the client wants to do something.  With the token, the server can make decisions about whether the client can perform a given action and even change the context of the action accordingly.